# Visual C++ equivalent to GCC experimental parallel for_each?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, parallel-processing

In GCC there is a convenient experimental feature for a parallel for_each, which means it works rather elegantly on iterator loops.

I'm not as familiar with VC++, but I'm dealing with a Windows specific project.

Is there a straight forward MS equivalent somewhere? My searches insofar keep getting thwarted by bumping into the .NET for_each, outdated threads, and the occasional OpenMP one (which works rather inefficiently on splitting iterators it seems).

Using VS2013 SP4, and need to keep 3rd party libs to ab absolute minimum and with no licensing hassles (hence me not using TBB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [Microsoft Parallel Patterns Library (PPL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx). It has a [parallel_for_each](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492857.aspx).

Comment: I had no idea it existed, bizarre it didn't crop up in my searches. Many thanks, will have a look at it. Would you happen to know if the implementation splits iterators efficiently, or does the silly thing of iterating the whole sequence each task/thread and only flaggs on/off the actual call per iteration? (which OMP seems to still do for me).
Thanks again.

Comment: @ThE_JacO I have not confirmed, but I have found ppl to be a high-quality implementation when I poked at it in other ways, so I assume so.